# How to install Proguard in Eclipse Juno for Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, proguard

I am very new to Proguard in Android. And I want to learn how to install and configure Proguard. I have searched much in SO, but couldn't find any links relevant to me. I cannot see any file at

> ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt

I cant even find the proguard folder in tools. So I believe that its not installed by default in my Eclipse. So can any guide me in this topic with some helpful links ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html):

> ProGuard is integrated into the Android build system, so you do not have to invoke it manually. ProGuard runs only when you build your application in release mode, so you do not have to deal with obfuscated code when you build your application in debug mode. Having ProGuard run is completely optional, but highly recommended.

To enable proguard you will need to export your application. File->Export->Android->Export Android Application. The resulting apk is obfuscated and ready for deployment in play store.

Answer (score 1):

When you create android project.

proguard.cfg file is automatically generated in the root directory of the project.
The default configuration file only covers general cases, so customize as per your needs.

**Enable it**

“Set the proguard.config  property in the /project.properties file. The path can be an absolute path or a path relative to the project’s root.”

**Case1**:    Just add proguard.config=proguard.cfg if the proguard.cfg is in projects root path.

**Case2**:    Configure from other location  [proguard.config=/path/to/proguard.cfg]

***Remove the “#” (or uncomment) the proguard configuring statement in project.properties. Which will be in commented initially.***

Check this blog for more details http://1belong2jesus.wordpress.com/

**Note:**

For Android SDK (r20 or higher)

There will be predefined proguard.config refered in project.properties [proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt].